# How do I set up multiple iOS apps in the same GitHub repository? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, github

More of a design question, please let me know if there's a more appropriate place to ask like [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

We currently have an iOS project that writes to a Firebase database. When the app releases to production, we don't want it to be able to write to the database, only read. For the time being, however, we have included both read and write abilities in the app for debugging purposes. We plan on refactoring the application into two separate applications: *one for the general public that will only read from the database*, and *one for our development team that will be writing for the database*.

I don't have questions about the refactoring/back-end. I am wondering if there is a way to set up GitHub so we push from two separate Xcode projects (one for reading, one for writing) into the same repository. My current solution is to create two separate GitHub repositories, but it would be nice if they could be merged into one.

Comment: This is a very bad way, you can  use Branches (staging,development,release), or use Targets create two target (Live , development ) this is the best work flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by making a separate branch for database manipulation. Because writing to the database is fairly static code (doesn't need to be updated/fixed much), we have two protected branches that members of the development team can open pull requests to merge into, called `develop` and `database`.

Answer (score 1):

Git have no concept of a 'project'. It looks at folders and files (and ignore empty directories). It starts from the root directory (where the .git file reside), down the directory tree. You can place as many files and folders as you wish (mind the disk space though). Text files (code) are small, so it's not an issue. I have some repos that have many small projects. As long as it's not resource heavy, it's not an issue.

One things to note though, when you make a change, it will go into the same line of commits, so I would advise mentioning the project name in the commit message.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two folder for two project in a GitHub repositories.But if you are free user, you only have max 1GB in one repositories

Answer (score 0):

A separate branch is asking for trouble. A bit of trouble now, an awful lot of trouble in the future. You will forever be integrating changes from one branch into another branch.

Step back away from git and look at Xcode. A project can have more than one target. Just create two targets instead of the usual one target. Each target can have its own .xcconfig file, where you set up how each target behaves. Git won't know anything about you having two targets, it just handles the one Xcode project that it sees.